# Javascript unable to find module in separate directory

Tags: javascript

Say I have the following directory structure:

```
some_folder
    -src
        - palisade_pke.js
        - palisade_pke.wasm
        - some_wrapper.js
    -test
        - simple_test.js
```

(You can see a simple example [iquah1/js_troubles](https://github.com/iquah1/js_troubles))

**some_wrapper.js**

- creates a class that wraps the functionality provided by `palisade_pke`
- meant to be imported (required?) by some other file (in this case, `simple_test.js`)

**simple_test.js**

- test the functionality provided by `some_wrapper.js`
- imports in `palisade_pke` and `some_wrapper`

---

`some_wrapper.js` contents:

```
const factory = require(".palisade_pke");
const _module = factory();

class SomeClass {
    constructor(params) { // params: array of values
        this.a = params[0];
        this.b = params[1];
        this.c = params.slice(2);
    }

    Printer(reps) {  // reps: int
        console.log(`Logging ${reps} times`);
        for (let i = 0; i < reps; i++) {
            console.log(`a: ${this.a}, b: ${this.b} and finally c: ${this.c}`);

        }
        return reps;
    }

    CreateCC(vec) { // vec: unused array
        const multDepth = 1;
        const scaleFactorBits = 50;
        const batchSize = 8;
        const securityLevel = _module.SecurityLevel.HEStd_128_classic;

        this.cc = new _module.GenCryptoContextCKKS(multDepth, scaleFactorBits, batchSize, securityLevel);
    }
}
```

and `simple_test.js`:

```
async function main(){
    let base = "../src/"
    const factory = require(base + "palisade_pke");
    const _module = factory();

    const cls = require(base + "some_wrapper");

    let a = new cls.SomeClass([1,2,3]);
    // and also tried 
    let a = cls.SomeClass([1,2,3]);

}
main().then(exitCode => console.log(exitCode));
```

---

When I run the tester I get

```
Error: Cannot find module 'palisade_pke'
Require stack:
- /XYZ/js_troubles/src/some_wrapper.js
- /XYZ/js_troubles/test/simple_test.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:93:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/XYZ/js_troubles/src/some_wrapper.js:1:17)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'XYZ/js_troubles/src/some_wrapper.js',
    'XYZ/js_troubles/test/simple_test.js'
  ]
}

Process finished with exit code 7
```

## Question:

How do I avoid this issue? I've tried adding the `.js` extension directly to all my `requires` but that doesn't seem to resolve my issue. Also, will the fact that I'm using a `require` raise issues for me later on when I try to use `SomeClass` in the `simple_test.js`?

Comment: You should use  : `const factory = require("./palisade_pke");` since it's a local module and not something you installed, or `const factory = require("../src/palisade_pke");` if you are in the test folder

Comment: Thank you so so much! Mind making your comment an answer so I can mark it as the solution?

Comment: no problem, glad i can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use :

```
const factory = require("./palisade_pke");
```

since it's a local module and not something you installed,

or

```
const factory = require("../src/palisade_pke");
```

if you are in the test folder